# Having trouble with FlatList in expo when I want to display multiple data that overflow the screen limit

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-flatlist

As I have multiple data that need to be display in the screen that will exceed the screen limit and I cannot scroll down to look at the other data. I researched and found that `SafeAreaView` and `FlatList` helps in solving the issue.

I tried to apply to my code:

```
<SafeAreaView style = {styles.container}>
      <FlatList>
      <Text style = {styles.header}>{paramKey} results:</Text>
      {
        todoData.map((item,index) => {
          return(
            <View key ={index}>
              <Text style ={styles.text}>{item.Halal}</Text>
              <Text style ={styles.text}>{item.OH}</Text>
              <Text style ={styles.text}>{item.Description}</Text>
              <Text style ={styles.text}>{item.Location}</Text>
            </View>          
            )
        })
      }
     </FlatList> 
    </SafeAreaView>
```

After applying, my data cannot be displayed anymore. So I referred to the document: https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist

It seems like `<FlatList> ends with />` and not `<FlatList> ends with </FlatList>`.

Example from the docs:

```
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={DATA}
        renderItem={({item}) => <Item title={item.title} />}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
```

I tried ending `<FlatList> with />` but it seems to be a syntax error in my IDE (Visual Studio code). How do I properly use `<FlatList>` in this case?

Comment: You need an item renderer (component) for each item; it's not clear what syntax error you had or why since you don't show it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Flatlist` do not accept `children` prop. Use `renderItem` prop instead:

```js
<SafeAreaView style = {styles.container}>
  <Text style = {styles.header}>{paramKey} results:</Text>
  <FlatList
    data={todoData}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
      <View>
        <Text style ={styles.text}>{item.Halal}</Text>
        <Text style ={styles.text}>{item.OH}</Text>
        <Text style ={styles.text}>{item.Description}</Text>
        <Text style ={styles.text}>{item.Location}</Text>
      </View>     
    )}
  />
</SafeAreaView>
```